# Easygui isn;t working as it should Python 3.8.1 on repl.it

Tags: python-3.x

Ok so easygui in python on repl.it isn't working as it should.

So whenever it runs I get in red text
Xopendisplay(MAGIC)
Must DL Open Symbol

There is no blue background. It is just black.
Can't drag dialogs.
Heres my code

```
import easygui
easygui.textbox()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpreter webservers like `repl.it` don't provide a display to use. Basically, in Linux, there's a process called `X Server` that is responsible for drawing on a connected display. This process doesn't have to run nor does a physical display have to be connected. Both are true for `repl.it` and why GUI applications won't work on it.

It will not connect to your display over the web.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. It ended up dealing with the broken version. Thank You!